# Kann etwas „oben“ statt „drauf“ sein?

Tags: word-usage, preposition

Ein Arbeitskollege von mir hat eine Sprachgewohnheit, der ich in dieser Form noch nie begegnet bin. Er sagt z.B.:

> Das steht auf der Tafel oben.

im Sinne von „Das steht auf der Tafel drauf“ oder einfach nur „Das steht auf der Tafel“ („oben“ bezieht sich hier nicht etwa auf eine Etage über uns). Ein anderes Beispiel, das er heute sagte:

> Dieser Rechner hat Windows XP oben.

Ähnlich verhält es sich auch bei der Beschreibung von Gegenständen, die sich auf etwas anderem befinden.

Ist das richtiges Deutsch? Könnte es regionsbedingt sein (wir sind in Berlin, ich weiß aber nicht genau woher er kommt)? Ich muss jedes Mal stutzen, wenn ich so etwas höre.

Comment: Habe ich auch schon gehört, weiß aber nicht, wo das gebräuchlich sein könnte - Vielleicht ist es auch nur ein Tick...

Comment: Zumindest im Süden \ Südwesten klingt das okay.  Sicherlich nicht schriftsprachlich, umgangssprachlich ist mir das aber durchaus geläufig.

Comment: Hochdeutsch ist das definitiv nicht. Ersteres wäre nur korrekt, wenn es sich darauf bezieht, dass der Text auf der Tafel oben steht (und unten etwas anderes), während letzeres überhaupt keinen Sinn ergibt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An dem Satz ...

> Das steht auf der Tafel oben.

habe ich, als ich ihn las, nichts besonderes gefunden. Als Schüler (Ich bin in den 1970er-und frühen 1980er-Jahren in Graz in die Schule gegangen) habe ich das oft gehört. Allerdings empfinde ich es trotzdem als stilistisch nicht besonders gelungen. Besser wäre ...

> Das steht auf der Tafel.

Also: Stilistisch schwach, aber ok.

Ob das Wort »oben« grammatisch in Ordnung ist, ist in Wahrheit eher eine semantische als eine grammatische.

Dort wo ich aufgewachsen bin, sind Formulierungen wie die folgenden durchaus in Ordnung:

> Kannst du mir sagen, was auf dem Plakat oben steht?
>   Auf dem Lieferwagen steht »wir bringen's« oben.

Mit »oben« ist »auf der Oberfläche« gemeint, und kann in diesem Sinn für Plakate, Tafeln, Boards und andere ähnliche Flächen verwendet werden.

---

Prinzipiell fällt mein persönliches Urteil über den Satz ...

> Dieser Rechner hat Windows XP oben.

gleich aus. Wenn der Tafel-Satz stilistisch schlecht war, ist der Rechner-Satz aber - meiner persönlichen Empfindung nach - katastrophal. Aber vermutlich trotzdem grammatisch ok (ich würde darauf aber keine großen Beträge wetten).

Für besser (aber noch immer schlecht) halte ich ...

> Dieser Rechner hat Windows XP drauf.

Stilistisch akzeptabel ist hingegen:

> Auf diesem Rechner ist Windows XP installiert.

(Noch besser wäre natürlich »Auf diesem Rechner ist Linux installiert.«)

Comment: +1 für die letzte Klammer! =D (Und für den Rest der Antwort, die auch meinem Sprachgefühl entspricht.)

Answer (score -2):

Mir ist diese Sprachgewohnheit unbekannt. Ich kenne nur dies:

> Das steht oben auf der Tafel.

Ich bin der Meinung, dass beide Sätze grammatikalisch falsch sind, wobei ich auch nicht den Inhalt des Zweiten Satzes verstanden habe.

Comment: Der zweite Satz soll bedeuten „Auf diesem Rechner ist Windows XP installiert“, wobei ich umgangssprachlich sagen würde „Auf diesem Rechner ist Windows XP drauf“.

Comment: Oh. Das ist trotzdem grammatikalisch falsch, wenn er drauf mit oben ersetzt

Comment: Wenn du der Meinung bist, dass etwas falsch ist,  wäre es durchaus angebracht diese zu begründen.  Das dir der Ausdruck unbekannt ist hat nicht unbedingt viel zu bedeuten - es gibt einen Unterschied zwischen "Das klingt für mich falsch."  und "Das ist falsch."

Comment: *grammatikalisch* ist es auf keinen Fall falsch - Denn da wo "oben" steht, darf ein Adverb des Ortes stehen. Ob es mit "oben" einen Sinn ergibt, hat mit der Grammatik nix zu tun.

Comment: Danke tofro für die Korrektur

Comment: Zwischen »Das steht oben auf der Tafel«, und »Das steht auf der Tafel oben«, besteht kein grammatikalischer Unterschied; im Deutschen herrscht bis auf wenige Ausnahme freie Verschiebbarkeit der Satzglieder, solange die Positionen der Verben beachtet werden.